# e.preventDefault() and return false are not preventing link from firing

Tags: javascript

I have seen several answers on here explaining that `e.preventDefault()` and `return false` can prevent a link from firing, but it is not working for me. Here is my code needed to replicate.

HTML

```
<div id="content">
<p class="foo">Paragraph</p>
<hr>
<a href="google.com" class="link">Link</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    var page_content_links = document.querySelectorAll('#content a');
    for (var i = 0; i < page_content_links.length; i++) {
        page_content_links[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                console.log('here');
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/beLn9146/4/

The behavior I want is that when the link is clicked, the browser does not follow and stays on the same page. The reason is more apparent when the full code is seen, but the issue is replicated above.

To troubleshoot, I added a console log to ensure that it was hitting `e.preventDefault()` and `return false`, and it is. I have also tried the two methods in isolation. I am using up to date Chrome.

**How can I prevent a link from firing, and why does my code not give this behavior?**

**Update: ** Updated code and JS fiddle to be consistent with event variable, and the issue still exists.

Comment: `e` in your code doesn't refer to the event object!

Comment: @Vohuman In that case `return false;` should stop redirection.

Comment: No, the error(an ReferenceError) stops the execution of the subsequent lines.

Comment: You're using `console.log`, can you not see the error being printed in your console *directly below* your logged `"here"`?

Comment: As the wrong answers have been deleted, I repeat here that the solution isn't to use `event` but to fix the interrnal event handler declaration to add the e argument

Comment: Don't know why this question is "off topic", but on this line: `page_content_links[i].addEventListener('click', function () {`, you need to put an `e` inside of `function()`, so the line becomes: `page_content_links[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {`. Everyone is confusing the first `event` with the `e` you call inside of the click handler.

Comment: you're not attaching any listeners https://jsfiddle.net/beLn9146/3/

Comment: apart from not referencing the `e`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't capture the event object, which is the first argument to the event handler function.

```
'click', function () {
```

So `e` is undefined:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

and when you try to call that as a function, it throws an exception (because it isn't one).

So it never reaches the line:

```
return false;
```

You need to name the argument:

```
'click', function (e) {
```

Comment: Ok here it reaches to the `return false`. https://jsfiddle.net/beLn9146/2/  Why still page getting refreshed?

Comment: If you check the jsfiddle the `DOMContentLoaded` handler doesn't run either to the click handler are never set anyway.

Comment: This does not work, will update question and JS fiddle as proof.

Comment: event is the DOMContentLoaded event! The error is in the function declaration

Comment: @Goose It should work. https://jsfiddle.net/beLn9146/5/  But the question is about, why did he tell such thing about return false.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy thanks, I see the mistake. When I posted the question, I assumed I had exhausted typographical mistakes as troubleshooting.

Comment: Did you check the OP's jsfiddle? It doesn't work, indeed. https://jsfiddle.net/beLn9146/10/

Comment: The JS Fiddle doesn't work for reasons unrelated to the code in the question. It has wrapped all the code in an onload handler, which fires **after** the DOM is ready, so the DOM Ready handler gets assigned too late to be run.

Comment: Your answer is no longer valid since the question is aldready edited. I think you should either update or delete your answer.

Comment: @Tresdin — The question should probably be reverted since it is now a completely different question.